# How can I generate URLs for uploaded files on my machine? (deployed Flask on Apache2 Debian)

Tags: python, apache, flask

In a Flask python function, I want to take a saved file and figure out the URL for it so I can input it into the Google Docs Viewer. So if I save 'test.pdf', it might return 'mydomain.com/www/html/myapp/packets/test.pdf'.

However I cannot figure out how to do this. It worked fine when I was in development, but broke since I deployed it. This is my apache2 config file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp
        ServerName mydomain.com
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/myapp/myapp.wsgi

        <Directory /var/www>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
        LogLevel info
        CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And my Python function (using AJAX to do the file upload):

```
@app.route('/uploadajax', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        pkt_filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], pkt_filename))

    return jsonify({'filename':'/var/www/html/myapp/packets/' + pkt_filename})
```

The problem is that I can't figure out where exactly mydomain.com is on the system. In development, I could just do mydomain.com/html/myapp/packets/test.pdf, and it would open in browser, but this doesn't work in deployment. Even though the DocumentRoot is /var/www/html/myapp, typing mydomain.com/packets/test.pdf into the address bar returns a 404 (even though it definitely exists on the system).

Another interesting thing is that os.cwd() in that Python function returns '/', although I'm not sure what the consequences of that are.

Any help?

Comment: Resolved using the Alias command.

    Alias /docs /var/.../packets

in the Apache2 config file.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html

Comment: Well worth making that the answer - that's accepted practice around here :-)  Glad you got it working!

Comment: Just FYI, what was most likely happening was that without the alias Apache was forwarding *all* requests on to your Flask app, which did not have a route to handle the `packets` endpoint.  Using the alias is better than serving the PDFs through Flask (if you do not need access control).